# Django application - store usernames and passwords in a msql database or openldap?

Tags: python, mysql, django, ldap, openldap

I am very new to django and web programming. Please excuse the dumb question. I want to create a web application with user authentication. I would like to create the application with django. What's better to store usernames and passwords in a msql database or LDAP on things like OpenLDAP, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Djangos integrated auth system stores credentials in a database by default. You are free to use any custom authentication backend, look here for a start https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for the fast reply! This helps a lot!